# Twitter API v1.1 media INIT error code 32

Tags: twitter, oauth, coldfusion, postman, lucee

I am trying to get the media_id for a media upload. See docs [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/media/upload-media/uploading-media/chunked-media-upload).

When using postman, my request is processed successfully and I get a response like this:

```
{
    "media_id": 1222234872222222401,
    "media_id_string": "1222734822222102201",
    "expires_after_secs": 86399
}
```

Unfortunately, using postman for our app is not an option. However, when I post a tweet with just text, the tweet is posted successfully using our own native code. I have also recreated the request from postman, and can successfully recreated the same oauth_signature needed for the media upload authorization. So I know that the backend is *working* in that I can create valid credentials, but I think I need some help structuring the POST request itself.

Here is the code (Lucee ColdFusion):

```
mediaEndpoint = "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json?command=INIT&total_bytes=10240&media_type=image/jpg&oauth_consumer_key=consumerKeyHere&oauth_token=tokenHere&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1653075352&oauth_nonce=UU5V18WLaPN&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=verifiedSignature";
cfhttp(url=mediaEndpoint, method="POST", result="init") {
        cfhttpparam(type="header", name="Content-Type", value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        cfhttpparam(type="header", name="Accepts", value="*/*");
        cfhttpparam(type="header", name="Accept-Encoding", value="gzip, deflate, br");
        cfhttpparam(type="header", name="Connection", value="keep-alive");
        cfhttpparam(type="body", value="command=INIT&media_type=#mediaParameters.media_type#&total_bytes=#mediaParameters.total_bytes#");
    }
```

But I keep getting the following 401:
`{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're supposed to send your authorization token in the header.  You're sending it in the URL as a query string.  Twitter's documentation would indicate you need to include an authorization header as such:

```
cfhttpparam(type="header", name="Authorization", value="Bearer: #YourAccessToken#");
```